# How to show another form after playing an SWF file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a form that contains a Shockwave Flash object. I want that after playing the file or in the middle of it by pressing a key another form is shown. What should I do? Should I use an event?

Here's the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "c:/intro.swf";
    axShockwaveFlash1.Forward();
    axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

And in Form2:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Close();
}
```

When I debug both forms are shown but I just want Form2.

Comment: How are you playing the SWF? (What object/control are you using?)

Comment: If `axShowckwaveFlash1` has an event for `Completed` or `Finsihed`, subscribe to it and show the new form when its done.

Comment: I dont think it has such event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `Form1` instance to the `Form2` constructor, and close it there, like:

```
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponents();

    form1.Hide();//hide the control from the user, or close it if it not the main form..
}
```

Or if you want it to close the `form1` instance when a button click then:

```
private Form1 _form1 = null;
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponents();

    _form1 = form1;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_form1 != null)
    {
        _form1.Hide();
    }
}
```

Initialize the form2 in form1:

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "c:/intro.swf";
axShockwaveFlash1.Forward();
axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);//"this here is the form1 instance itself"
form2.Show();
```

Comment: thanks Jalal.I use this method but why is the program on progress even if I close form2?and debuging never stop?

Comment: Because you didn't close the form1 as will, remember we hide it. so handle the form2 `Closing` event and close the form1 instance as well.

Comment: private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Close();
        }

Comment: no, here you are creating a new `Form1` and closing it. you should use the other solution : private Form1 _form1 = null;
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponents();

    _form1 = form1;
} Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) { _form1.Close(); }

Answer (score 0):

you can also use timer to check weather the movie is playing or not,if not then open new form which is form2

```
 private void flash_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = @"C:\Users\Adil M\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TProject\a.swf";
        int a = axShockwaveFlash1.MovieData.Length;
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

now code on timer event

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!axShockwaveFlash1.IsPlaying())
        {
            Fome2 fobj = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            timer1.stop();

            fobj.show();

        }
        else if(axShockwaveFlash1.IsPlaying())
        {
        }
    }
```

this code is working for you only when your movie is complete or for any key you can also do it in timer
thanx